# How to add Schema location and XSI dynamically to an XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Hi all i am creating an application to generate an `XML` file dynamically. In this i would like to add `schemalocation` and `XSI` to the `XML` `Root` how can i do this. I would like to add the following

```
xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile"

xsi:SchemaLocation="http://www.irs.goc/efile ReturnData941.xsd"
```

and

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance"
```

This is my sample `XML` code that was generated dynamically

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

doc.AppendChild(docNode);

XmlNode returnData = doc.CreateElement("ReturnData");
XmlAttribute documnetCount = doc.CreateAttribute("documentCount"); // after this i would like to add that schema
returnData.Attributes.Append(documnetCount);
```

So that i should get my `XML` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReturnData documentCount=""  xsi:SchemaLocation="http://www.irs.goc/efile ReturnData941.xsd" xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need add a attribute like

```
        XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", " ");
        attr.Value = "http://www.irs.goc/efile ReturnData941.xsd";
        returnData.Attributes.Append(attr);
```

Comment: Damn, for me it doesn't work. What happens is that C# instead of `xsi` adds `d1p1` so attribute looks like `xsi:schemaLocation="http://some.url.com"`. I tried adding `xsi` as namespace, but in vain...

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is the best way of approaching things? Many validation APIs allow you to specify the schema location and instance document location independently, and that's likely to be more efficient than storing the schema location within the instance.

Generally I'm sceptical about xsi:schemaLocation anyway. If you're validating the instance, that's often because you don't trust it, and if you don't trust it, why should you trust its xsi:schemaLocation?